# How to grab pixels from a floating point rendertexture in unity?

Tags: unity-game-engine

I use the following code to grab the pixels from a rendertexture, pixelsRT, which has the format RenderTextureFormat.ARGBFloat

```
public Color[] getPixels()
{
    Texture2D temp = new Texture2D(width, height, TextureFormat.RGBAFloat, false);
    var oldRT = RenderTexture.active;
    RenderTexture.active = pixelsRT;
    temp.ReadPixels(new Rect(0, 0, temp.width, temp.height), 0, 0, false);
    temp.Apply();
    RenderTexture.active = oldRT;
    Color[] pixels = temp.GetPixels();
    qitools.Tools.Destroy(temp);
    return pixels;
}
```

This works fine as long as the shader writes values in the 0-59 range, but once it uses the full -inf to inf range, the pixel values returned gets clamped.

To make sure Unity indeed can handle the full range, I wrote this test code:

```
Texture2D tex = new Texture2D(10, 10, TextureFormat.RGBAFloat, false);
Color[] col = new Color[10 * 10];
col[0] = new Color(-10000, 0, 0, 1);
tex.SetPixels(col);
tex.Apply();
col=tex.GetPixels();
Debug.Log("Tester: "+col[0]);
```

This outputs (-10000,0,0,1) as expected.

So, it seems conversion from RenderTexture to Texture2D is not able to retain the full range. Also, I suspect the precision is lowered during the conversion as well.

I need to read the full range of the pixels in the RenderTexture on the CPU, but I am stuck. Can anyone help?

EDIT: I should point out this is not for rendering pixels, but for computing data. So access to the full precision and range that the floating point texture natively supports is needed.

EDIT2: I discovered the problem is exclusively with HDRP, in the regular pipeline all works well. Unfortunately my project is HDRP only.

Apparently some unwanted post processing pass is capping the data written by the shaders. I have tried to disable all post processing in the volumes, but I have not been able to locate the culprit...

Comment: color should be either in float(0,1f), or int(0,255), what do you mean the full range? It's not realistic...

Comment: @thelghome RGBAFloat is 32 bit floating point per channel, supporting the full range of a float. Not supported on every platform, but I do not care about those who doesnt. As you can see from my second example over this works as expected. See the Unity documentation for the range: https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/TextureFormat.RGBAFloat.html

Comment: the precision is still float32 when it return values between 0f-1f. Logically, there won't be a value more than 1 in this case for color.

Comment: @thelghome This is not for colors, but for computation of large amounts of data. Need the full range that the floating point texture actually supports, with max precision. So, the question remains, how to workaround this in Unity.

Comment: are you trying to store some depth data, or position data in rgb, for the use of shader?

Comment: @thelghome No, I am computing large amounts of data on the GPU, and need exact values from the computations read out from the float texture to the CPU. But the common way of doing this in Unity seems to truncate the data.

Comment: seems likely you can only remap the data range to 0-1 in GPU or shader output, then remap the data back to integer in C#.